# Why cannot I use graphics.h header file for my C program in VS code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, graphics, syntax-error, bgi

I am trying a program of DDA algorithm to draw a line using graphics in c. I tried to use the header file graphics.h in Visual Studio Code and it threw an error that the header file does not exist. Why is it happening?[Here is the screenshot of my code and the error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khtQh.png)

I tried writing a program and i thought it would draw a line by giving coordinates of both starting and ending points but it threw an error that there is no such file or directory exists as graphics.h

Comment: Looks like Turbo C code, and that it was meant to be compiled in the Turbo C compiler sold by Borland and popular in the 1990s.   Hence, the code has dependencies on the Turbo C graphic libraries and headers too.   I think you'll only meet with frustration trying to compile this in Vis Studio.  You might search the web for a "Turbo C to Vis Studio conversion library."  Sometimes you can get lucky and find stuff like that, as Turbo C was super-popular in its day -- lots of Turbo C code still floating around.

Comment: Another option is to find Turbo C on the web and install it -- except it's a 16-bit app and you'll also need WinXP or earlier to run it, and the compiled apps you make.   Also, I found this  https://developerinsider.co/download-turbo-c-for-windows-7-8-8-1-and-windows-10-32-64-bit-full-screen/  -- see, Turbo C was so popular people can't let it go.  I haven't tried this software, but the website claims it's Turbo C++ for Windows 7, 8, 8.1, 10 and Windows 11 (32-64 bit).   Good luck and best wishes to you.

Comment: One last thing -- please always submit code in plain text, not sreenshots.  Although,, yes it is true, it didn't make a difference this time.   But sometime, it will surely make a difference -- because people who help you will want to copy and paste your code and compile to see if they same error comes.   This would be very unhappy to re-type all that code to help you.

Comment: You need WinBGI or other emulator of BGI to use it on "newer" OS than MS-DOS ...